# How to configure store with different api slice reducers with different base URLs in RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to create different API slices with RTK Query with different API endpoints base URLs. For example:

First API slice (apiSlice.js):

```
const baseURL = "https://example.com/api";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL,
    ...
});

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: baseQuery,
    endpoints: builder => ({
        ...
    });
});
```

Second API slice (webApiSlice.js):

```
const baseURL = "https://example.com/webapi";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL,
    ...
});

export const webApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'webapi',
    baseQuery: baseQuery,
    endpoints: builder => ({
        ...
    });
});
```

And this is my store configuration (store.js):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import { webApiSlice } from './api/webApiSlice';
import { apiSlice } from './api/apiSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [webApiSlice.reducerPath]: webApiSlice.reducer,
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authReducer,
        ... // other reducers
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(webApiSlice.middleware)
});

export default store;
```

I've to Mention that `webApiSlice.js` is for fetching auth endpoints with `/webapi` address and `apiSlice.js` is for normal endpoints with `/api` address.

I got this warning in the console:

> Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store.
> Features like automatic cache collection, automatic refetching etc. will not be available.

How can I config correctly both apiSlice and webApiSlice with different routes in my store?

Comment: Have you tried `middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat([webApiSlice.middleware, apiSlice.middleware])` ?

Comment: Yes I tried concating the middlewares like this but I'm not sure that this is the actual solution for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should do this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import { webApiSlice } from './api/webApiSlice';
import { apiSlice } from './api/apiSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [webApiSlice.reducerPath]: webApiSlice.reducer,
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authReducer,
        ... // other reducers
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware()
     .concat(webApiSlice.middleware)
     .concat(apiSlice.middleware)
});

export default store;
```